# Java Mail API password Verification

Tags: java, swing, email, jakarta-mail, validation

I am using Java Mail API to send an email. So I am getting email and password from user, I just want to check the password when they are enter their password, but I don't get any ideas to verify the password in Java Mail API. Can anyone help?

Question 2:

```
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
{
  return new PasswordAuthentication("xxx@gmail.com","*");
}
```

What is use of the above the above method

Comment: *"verify the password"*  What 'password'?  DYM verify or validate the email address?

Comment: 1) Don't hit the 'back button' to edit a question.  Instead click the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14271408/edit) in the question. 2) Ask one question per question.  3) Use code formatting.  To do that, select the code sample and click the `{}` button above the message posting/editing form.

Comment: @Andrew , In Java Mail API , we can send the email to anybody right through correct SMTP, But if we enter a wrong email or wrong Password for a Respective smpt server, The Mail API informs me when i invoke mail.send() method  send an email only rather initial.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @andrew i will follow it from hereafter.

Comment: *"The Mail API informs me when i invoke mail.send() method send an email only rather initial."*  I understand that up to *"mail.send() method.."*  Can you rephrase the last part of that sentence?

Comment: ya right, i want to validate the email and Password   before invoking mail.send() method friend, that is my question andrew ..

Comment: That is simply not possible.

Comment: fine, is there any possibility option is there to verify email and password in java in any API ..???

Comment: Hope this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8647099/1057230), might help your cause. Though I failed to understand the question completely, but this **getPasswordAuthentication() is called when password authentication is needed. Subclasses should override the default implementation, which returns null.**

Comment: Try sending it!  If you get a 'wrong password' or 'no such address' return mail, it failed.  Note that you don't seem to be getting that this is not possible in any Java API, or in any API in C, C++, C#, PHP, Perl..  Because *it is not possible to validate an email address/password short of trying to use it.*

Comment: @antrew well it is not good idea , In case  the "E-Mail " and "Password" is correct the mail will send, my question is to check before send Mail. Anyway  thanks for  your reply....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To validate the password you have to use it.  You don't have to send a message, but you do have to connect to the server and authenticate.  Use the Transport.connect method.  You can close the connection right away if you're not going to send the message soon, or you can save the Transport object for use later when you send the message and close it when you're done.  Note that if you're waiting for user input between the Transport.connect (to validate the password) and the Transport.sendMessage (to send the message), the server may time out the connection and you'll have to reconnect before sending.